# Flutter: Custom ExpansionTile

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to alter the expansion tile in flutter? Specifically I want to remove the dividers it creates when it expands. Also I want to adjust its padding. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the ExpansionTile source code from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d927c9331005f81157fa39dff7b5dab415ad330b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart#L176-L184 and edit it as you want and make your custom ExpansionTile!!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the source of `ExpansionTile`

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d927c9331005f81157fa39dff7b5dab415ad330b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart#L176-L184

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColor
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColor
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColor.end = widget.backgroundColor;
```

you can derive what you can influence by wrapping the element in a `Theme` for example by modifying `dividerColor`

```
_borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
```

```
final theme = Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.yellow);
return Theme(data: theme, child: ExpansionTile(...));
```

similar with `_headerColor`, `_iconColor`, `_backgroundColor`.
If you need more customization, you can always copy the source and customize it to your liking.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer is editing a source code a better practice?I had a similar question and I looked at the expansion tile source code and the borders were being applied when the tile was expanded I simply commented that piece of code because I don't need them and it worked for me, should that be done or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @maheshmnj If you change the code in `~/.pub-cache/...` or somewhere inside `~/.flutter/...` you won't have much fun with Flutter - no fun at all - don't do that, like ever. Changes in that directory might get lost at any time. If you copy the source into your own project then the maintenance burden is on you, because when the Flutter team makes changes you won't even get notified and your code might become stale. If the widget just doesn't allow any other way to customize its behavior to your needs (as in above example at that time) then copying might be the lesser burden.

Answer (score 25):

For remove dividers simply warp with `Theme` widget and make divider color transparent.

```
final theme = Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent);
return Theme(data: theme, child: ExpansionTile(...));
```

Comment: This answer is too brief and does not provide a sufficient explanation of how it solves the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

comment out

```
//        border: Border(
//          top: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
//          bottom: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
//        ),
```

from expansion_tile.dart

Comment: This is not a good practice as when the flutter team updates their code it would get overwritten please read the comment above from @GunterZochbauer